# change tableview cell color to click

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-8, listener

I have a TableView that represents a calendar. Each cell is one day. and I want to add an event to the cells. When the cell is clicked, the background must be changed to red ... it should be possible to select more than one cell

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far, so we can understand how to help.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YhlIuQySsPeYn4O7aOmC2kU5kod7sSZm 
This is the link of my project ... you must execute the MainRank class and select a very high rank (1 year is fine). Then you will see the calendar with the dates and if you click on a cell, the background color will change correctly. but if you lower and raise with the scrooll, the selection is distorted.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just selection that you need you can use a selection model with multiple selection an cell selection mode.

```
table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
```

#### CSS stylesheet

```css
.table-cell {
    -fx-selection-bar: red;
    -fx-selection-bar-non-focused: red;
}
```

---

If you don't want to use the selection model, you need to store the data in your items and use a custom `TableCell`

```
public class DayCell extends TableCell<Week, Boolean> {

    {
        setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
            if (!isEmpty() && getItem() != null && evt.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                WritableValue<Boolean> property = (WritableValue<Boolean>) getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue((Week) getTableRow().getItem());
                property.setValue(!getItem());
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            setStyle(null);
        } else {
            setStyle(item ? "-fx-background-color: red;" : null);
        }
    }
}
```

```
column.setCellFactory(c -> new DayCell());
```

This requires the `ObservableValue`s returned by the `cellValueFactory` to implement `WritableValue<Boolean>` in a way that stores the data in table item class. Using a `BooleanProperty` stored in this class would do the trick.

---

I don't think it's a good idea to use `TableView` in this case though. It's not designed to display a fixed size non-resizable grid.

Comment: Hi, I have followed your advice. but I have an error when column.setCellFactory (c -> new DayCell ());
do you think you can check my project link and translate your idea

Comment: @MichaelSalinasRios You need to change `Week` to the item type of the `TableView`. I just used this name since it's a reasonable assumption that you're using the days of the week as columns.

Comment: Yes I do. in the column statement. with my WeekDates class, but when you load the calendar it paints the entire entire column